# iOS SDK for Mountain Lion

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, ios4, xcode4.3

I upgraded to Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard on my macbook. In my macbook I had iOS SDK 4.3 and Xcode 4.2. Now I am downloading Xcode 4.4 for Mountain Lion.

In my iMac I have OSX Lion and it has iOS 5.1 SDK with Xcode 4.3.

What I want to know is should I download again iOS SDK 5.1 for my macbook? OR could I copy Developer folder from my iMac to macbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the downloaded App file that you used to install the SDK. The app file can then be run on different Mac systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate them, so you will end up downloading it anyway.  No need to copy it from your other computer.